Critical point of perturbed stratifiable function has no cluster point
Given a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and a smooth manifold $\mathcal{M}$. Now, consider the set
$$
S(v)=\{x:0\in x\circ(\nabla_{\mathcal{M}} f(x)+N_{\mathcal{M}}(x)+v)\}.
$$
Whether the following statement is right: for almost all $v\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $S(v)$ has no cluster point. Here $\circ$ is element-wise product.
